# In Matlab, How to eliminate empty columns from the cell array?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, is-empty

So in 3 X 18 cell array, 7 columns are empty and I need a new cell array that's 3 X 11. Any suggestions without going for looping ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the following cell array. Its second column consists only of `[]`, so it should be removed.

```
>> c = {1 , [], 'a'; 2, [], []; 3, [], 'bc'}
c = 
    [1]    []    'a' 
    [2]    []      []
    [3]    []    'bc'
```

You can compute a logical index to tell which columns should be kept and then use it to obtain the result:

```
>> keep = any(~cellfun('isempty',c), 1);  %// keep columns that don't only contain []
keep =
     1     0     1                        %// column 2 should be removed
>>  result = c(:,keep)
result = 
    [1]    'a' 
    [2]      []
    [3]    'bc'
```

*How it works*:

1. `cellfun('isempty' ,c)` is a matrix the same size as `c`. It contains `1` at entry `(m,n)` if and only if `c{m,n}` is empty.
2. `~cellfun('isempty' ,c)` is the logical negation of the above, so it contains `1` where `c` is not empty.
3. `any(~cellfun('isempty' ,c), 1)` applies `any` to each column of the above. So it's a row vector such that its `m`-th entry equals `1` if any of the cells of `c` in that column are non-empty, and `0` otherwise.
4. The above is used as a logical index to select the desired columns of `c`.

Comment: This is simply awesome solution ! exactly what I needed. Can you also please break it down ( keep and result parts) , I want know how it works :)

Comment: I'm glad this is what you needed. I've added an explanation breaking it down

Answer (score 1):

Use `cellfun` to detect elements, then from that find columns with empty elements and delete those:

```
cellarray(:, any(cellfun(@isempty, cellarray), 1)) = [];
```

If instead you'd like to keep columns with at least one non-empty element, use `all` instead of `any`.

For example:

```
>> cellarray = {1 2 ,[], 4;[], 5, [], 3}

    [1]    [2]    []    [4]
     []    [5]    []    [3]

>> cellarray(:,any(cellfun(@isempty, cellarray), 1))=[]

cellarray = 

    [2]    [4]
    [5]    [3]
```